# Open an anchor link inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to prevent an `anchor` link to open on the `document` `body` and instead render inside a `div`. I've used `e.preventDefault()` but I think JQuery isn't targeting that event.

I'm programmatic-ly creating a `ul` and appending `li`'s to it from `array` items then appending the `ul` to a `div`. The structure looks like this:

```
//this is just a structure, not the actual HTML 
    <div id="results">    
     <ul> .ulStyle
        <li>  .list-group-item 
          -header 
          -p .lead
          -a .anchorStyle
       </li>      
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Then, I add `classes` to each `element`. Everything but the `ul` is getting the `class` and I think that may be why it's not targeting the `anchors`.

**jQuery**:

```
$(function(){

 console.info('** anchor-tag click handler **') 

/*
  I've tried variations on the targeting from a 
  single $('.anchorStyle') to what you see below. 
*/

$('div #results ul .ulStyle li .list-group-item a .anchorStyle')
    .click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#results').empty();
       $('#results').load( this.getAttribute('href') );
       console.log('anchor clicked...');
     });  

});
```

I get the first `console` message on `reload` but not the second `on click`.

**Questions:**

1. Do I need a class on the `ul` to target it properly? I'm only adding
   it to the `ul` for that purpose.
2. Does this piece of code execute with everything else and the `ul` may not have been created yet? JS/jQuery should
   still `bind` and keep listening to an `event` if it exists - or in this
   case, find the `element` I'm targeting after the `click event` fires,
   no?

Comment: Well you are removing everything in #results on the first click, the `a` is gone after that. Unless `this.getAttribute('href')` loads in a new one dynamically that supports the same selector. If so you need to use [`.on('click', ...)`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Too many spaces in selector....and far too specific also. Don't need all those tags in that selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems in the code to point out...

First is that the selectors are not right. You have a `space after your element and it's class` which is wrong (Eg:`ul .ulStyle` here .ulStyle is considered as a child of ul).The selector must be like this

`$('div#results ul.ulStyle li.list-group-item a.anchorStyle')`

Notice I have removed the spaces between the element and it's class..

Even after getting this changes done it still won't work for you because the elements are added dynamically. Taking this line from the OP

> I'm programmatic-ly creating a ul and appending li's to it from array items then appending the ul to a div.

So this calls for a need to **use event delegation**

The syntax must change to

`$(document).on('click','div#results ul.ulStyle li.list-group-item a.anchorStyle',function(){//your stuff here});`

Further you can keep the selector simple as 
`'#results a.anchorStyle'`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the spaces and the `eventListener` on the `document`. I'm getting the click to respond now and preventing default. I can't check weather the link renders inside the `div` though because I'm trying to go via `codepen` and it's not permitted. Any ideas other than trying `jsonp` in the `dataType` ?

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working example with your structure:

```js
$('#results ul li a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.href);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">    
  <ul>
    <li> 
      <header>HEADER</header>
      <p></p>
      <a href="/a">ANCHOR</a>
    </li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```